# how to copy specific columns through csv file to postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

```
import psycopg2
import time


def read_database():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="capitadb", user="capita_user", password="capita_user",
                                host = "127.0.0.1", port = "5432")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        start_time = time.time()
        cur.execute("COPY stagging(Activity_ID,F_Qtr,Fiscal_Week_Num,Manager,MBadge) FROM '/home/vivek/Downloads/dell_data.csv'  DELIMITER',' CSV;;")

        print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
        print("Operation done successfully")
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: %s" % e)
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_database()
```

Here we have 15 columns in csv file, but we want to copy only 4 columns. How will we achive that without extracting data in any file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `COPY FROM STDIN` functionality - http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from. You will be able to provide file-like object to that function. You can use [itertools](https://kite.com/python/docs/itertools) module for that

```
from itertools import chain, islice
class some_magic_adaptor(object):
    def __init__(self, src):
        self.src = chain.from_iterable(src)
    def read(self, n):
        return "".join(islice(self.src, None, n))


def read_csv():
    for line in open(csv_filename):
        yield transform_line(line)

file_like_object_for_postgresql = some_magic_adaptor(read_csv())
```

Comment: But is it possible with postgresh copy command rather then stdio because my data volume is too high like 20 GB?

Comment: Updated the answer. You will need to implement `transform_line` function